# VBA Code to extract selected data from Excel to .txt file

Tags: excel, vba

I found a code that enables me to save selected column data from excel to a new .txt file, I need a help to update the code to save the files automatically to a specific folder path and rename the files automatically as a function of the selected data (row and column) header.

Is that possible?!

[image: sample sheet view]

```
Sub ExportRangetoFile()
'Update 20130913
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim saveFile As String
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
WorkRng.Copy
wb.Worksheets(1).Paste
saveFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
wb.SaveAs Filename:=saveFile, FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
wb.Close
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Where should the file be saved and what name should it be save under?

Answer (score 0):

Check the posible changes, good luck

```
Sub ExportRangetoFile()
'Update 20130913
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim saveFile As String
    Dim WorkRng As Range
'----------------
    Const YourFileName = "FileName_"
    Const YourPathToSave = "C:\Users\miguel.cortez\Desktop\" '"C:etc" ' remember add a \ at the end
    Const YourSheetSource = "Sheet 2"
'----------------

    On Error Resume Next
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Range("A1:A" & CountRowsWithData(YourSheetSource, 1)) 'if you know the     column or range replace --> 'Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
    WorkRng.Copy
    wb.Worksheets(1).Paste
    saveFile = YourPathToSave & YourFileName & GetIdVirtuallyUnique
    wb.SaveAs Filename:=saveFile, FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
    wb.Close
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetIdVirtuallyUnique() As String
    Const FormatDate = "yyyy_mm_dd_HH_MM_SSS"
    GetIdVirtuallyUnique = Format(Now, FormatDate)
End Function
'Column number ex. A=1,B=2 c= 3 etc
Public Function CountRowsWithData(SheetToCheck_ As String, columnToCheck_ As Double) As Double
    Sheets(SheetToCheck_).Select
    Cells(1, columnToCheck_).Select
    CountRowsWithData = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```